# custom overlay is not transparent

Tags: ios, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm doing something fairly simple. I created a simple NIB with just a segmented control. Mainly for test purposes.
I'm trying to use this NIB to load into a UIImagePickerController overlay. But when loaded, the overlay is not transparent. Simply showing the white background and the button in the center on top of the camera view. I tried overlay.opaque = NO with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewTest;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *switchButtonTest;
```

Later on, I have this method (mainly from the APLViewController example from apple

```
- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {
        imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ViewTest" owner:self options:nil];
        self.viewTest.frame = imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
        imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.viewTest;
        self.viewTest = nil;
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the white background view, change its color to `clearColor` (or don't use it in the first place). To make the segmented control less opaque, set its `alpha` to, say, `0.2`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this was driving me nuts! Your suggestion works, I actually changed the color to "default" (go figure why it's not the default setup) and it did the trick as well.

Comment: If you are someone who doesn't know about `alpha`, you might want to read my discussion of views: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_visibility_and_opacity

Answer (score 0):

Fill clear color in self.viewTest background.